# (UK) Employment law - reduction in hours, no change of contract, claiming back earnings

Tags: employment

A 17 year old employee in full-time education is contracted to 20 hours per week of shifts at a large UK company. However, after only 2 months, their team leader tells them informally that they can only offer 10 hours per week.

6 months later and the employee is still offered only 10 hours per week, and the company still has not:

- informed the employee in writing
- amended their contract
- asked employee to sign a new contract

The employee has repeatedly asked for more hours and seen other personnel hired into their department, showing that additional hours were available.

Is this a serious breach of contract? Is there any recourse to recoup the almost 2500 GBP of lost earnings?

Employee wishes to keep the job if possible, but at their contracted 20 hours.

Comment: Does the contract *guarantee* 20 hours ?

Comment: No, and it seems on reflection there is a clause in the contract that means they can change the working hours whenever they like. Really annoying.

Comment: @user2470281 Since this likely depends on contract specifics that we don't know, your best bet is to consult the Citizens Advice Bureau.